# Does a minus charge represent two electrons?

Tags: organic-chemistry, formal-charge

In OH- 's lewis structure, we put 8 dots around O and then the H, thus, it now has 10 electrons, instead of 9 (as 8 electrons for O and 1 for H), and thus we say that it has a charge of minus one.

Am I correct?

But in organic mechanisms, many books put two dots over OH and the bring them to a bond, or vice versa, thus, I assume that the dash over OH or the minus sign means two electrons, this confuses me.

Comment: The minus sign means a charge of minus one, there is no doubt about that. As for the two dots, these represent an electron pair, which has nothing to do with the overall charge. Many neutral molecules have them as well.

Comment: This forced me to remember a nuclear physicist that made her way thinking there is an anion called ammonia.

Answer (score 3):

No, you are mistaken.

Oxygen has 6 electrons (dots) on its outer shell in the Bohr model and two on the inner shell. The inner shell is, under lewis rules, irrelevant. So the outer shell, 6 out of 8, needs to be put on the 4 sides of the O: 2 doubles, 2 singles. Ignore the color note for the moment, that's for physicists view below.

[image]

Then comes H with one dot, connecting to one singleton via the bond. Now comes the negative charge `-`, which adds another electron (dot) to the last singleton, giving us a full 8 dots: 7 of these are *held* by the Oxygen, one *belongs* to the Hydrogen, but shared to the Oxygen:

[image: OH-]

I am a physicist. We go further and talk about orbitals that each can have 2 electrons. Hydrogen has only one, which means it has a partially filled 1s-orbital. As we go up in the periodic table we start to fill the orbitals: first each orbital gets one in order of which one has the lowest energy needed to stock them there, then they start to get their second electron, as soon as that position becomes the most energetically *cheap* position to put it. Starting with Selene (and again Lanthan!), that can become a mess, but we are at Oxygen and Hydrogen, no danger here.

Oxygen has 8 electrons total: First we filled 1s-orbital with two. Then we put one to the 2s-orbitals, then one on the next energetic stable ones: 2p<sub>x</sub>, 2p<sub>y</sub> and 2p<sub>z</sub> orbitals - there are no 1p orbitals. This means we have 2 left. So we fill up 2s fully and  one (commonly 2p<sub>x</sub>) of the p-orbitals fully and are left with two partially filled 2p orbitals (2p<sub>y</sub> & 2p<sub>z</sub>), telling us Oxygen can do two single-p-bonds or one double-p-bond using a *smeared* orbital in the yz-plane.

One of these p-orbitals now connects with the hydrogen's 1s orbital, creating the bond to the oxygen's 2p<sub>y</sub>. The negative charge ends on the last 2p<sub>z</sub>-orbital. Why we do that? Because it's [pretty](http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/ions_orbitals.html) and we claim that the electrons are *smeared* all over the shell of these orbitals. Electrons are not positional, they have a volume where they might be, and that's what each orbital stands for.

Comment: It's bit unusual to use a shell model and then label the occupying electrons with s, p, d, f...

Comment: @Zhe I know, but it's how you go from Bohr to Orbitals the *easy* way. the *hard* way is to solve a lot of formulae with all the quantum numbers to get which one is the next one that's energetically best.

Answer (score 0):

By convention, Lewis formula often represent two electrons by a dash instead of dots.  This dash might appear like a minus sign to represent a negative charge, especially in absence of visual comparison.  The two concepts however are independent of each other.

Though the equilibrium of the autodissociation of propanol likely favors the non-dissociated state on the left hand side, one can describe the underlying the reaction with the upper reaction equation equation.  This one omits explicit non-bonded valence electrons altogether:

[image]

At a lower level, in course of the formation of the alcoholate, *both* electrons  of the $\ce{O-H}$ bond are transferred to oxygen, the more electronegative atom.  To discern non-bonded valence electrons of Lewis formulae and charges, some sketchers offer special signs enclosed by a circle (lower reaction equation).*

Further, if one would remove one electron from the alcoholate oxygen, the molecule would be neutral - and because of an unpaired valence electron, a [radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_(chemistry)) as shown for hydroxyde ion and hydroxyl radical:

[image]

(image credit: English [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_(chemistry))).

On occasion, authors indeed use this special notation to discern charges and Lewis electrons:

[image]

[image]

Both photos display equations in Warren's retrosynthesis book, p. 111.

* To highlight the complete electron transfer, the $\ce{O-H}$ bond in the lower equation was extended beyond typical proportion.

references:

Warren, S.; Wyatt, P.  Organic Synthesis: The Disconnection Approach. Wiley,  **2008**, ISBN 978-0-470-71237-5 ([landing page](https://www.wiley.com/en-ie/Organic+Synthesis:+The+Disconnection+Approach,+2nd+Edition-p-9780470712368) of the book at the publishers).

Answer (score 0):

Non-bonded pairs of electrons (lone pairs) are shown in Lewis structures either as two dots, or as a line (like bonded pairs).

If you are using a line for lone pairs and are showing negative charges in the same figure, it is good practice to circle the negative (and positive) charges so that there is no confusion.

> Does a minus charge represent two electrons?

It does not. It does not represent electrons at all. It represents an excess of negative charges (typically from electrons) compared to positive charges (typically from protons). Because you don't show inner electrons in Lewis structures, and don't show protons at all, figuring out the charge of a species (or the formal charge of an atom) has to be done as a separate calculation whose result you would add to your  Lewis structure or other representation.